# Reverse order of the keys for an Object.entries() method

Tags: javascript

The Object.entries() method seem to output the keys in an ascending order:

```
// array like object with random key ordering
const anObj = { 100: 'a', 2: 'b', 7: 'c' };
console.log(Object.entries(anObj)); // [ ['2', 'b'], ['7', 'c'], ['100', 'a'] ]
```

I am not sure it this is always the case, but if it is so, is there any way of reversing the order?

Comment: Objects are not ordered, `entries` might output anything. Use an array if you need a specific order.

Comment: _The Object.entries() method seem to output the keys in an ascending order_ No, the object literal is sorted like that, Object.entries() doesn't change any order

Comment: it is always the case for keys who could read as 32 bit integer numbers (like indices of arrays).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just reverse the array before logging it:

```js
const anObj = { 100: 'a', 2: 'b', 7: 'c' };
console.log(Object.entries(anObj).reverse());
```

But keep in mind that property names *should not be relied upon to be ordered* - it's not in the spec. Better to explicitly select properties in your desired order - perhaps use a `sort` function first.